# Sharing to Facebook using ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I have read through the questions here and none approach the issue I'm having.
I use the following code to share a URL on Facebook :

```
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
facebookIntent.setType("text/plain");          
facebookIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,msSpecialData.mShareData.url);
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

This normally works fine, it start Facebook application and takes the user to the share section with the URL i passed. **However**! 5% of the time this code will only start the Facebook application on the news feed and it will not share, the user has to go back to my app and share again for it to work.

My theory is that the Facebook application sometimes takes a longer time to start, hence not going to the share section? 
Does anyone else face this issue ?

Comment: I never did no .. I guess it`s just facebook being a bit slow and not being able to process the request ?

Comment: Yeah even i am experiencing the same. sometimes it is just posting the empty status without the url